# 422 Unprocessable Entity during fulfillment API call

Tags: shopify

I am receiving a 422 Unprocessable Entity error when attempting to add a tracking number to a fulfillment to an order via a POST to the below url with the message body below. The order is still open and all lines should be fulfilled with the same tracking number. The error body received is "All line items of a fulfillment must use the same fulfillment service". I am able to authenticate successfully first and the GET API for this order works correctly.

https://*.myshopify.com/admin/orders/{order id}/fulfillments.json

Comment: Can you post the payload you're sending, as well as the order id? That would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a single fulfillment where line items cannot be contained in the same shipment.  Check the line items you are trying to fulfill, if one of them uses a different service, you won't be able to create that fulfillment.

Instead you'll need to create N separate fulfillments where N is the distinct number of fulfillment services for the line items in that order.

Comment: Yes, we found that one of the items on the order has a different value for fulfillment_service. Thanks